# How to make jquery droppable aply hoverClass exactly when mouse on droppable area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-droppable

Hover class applied when mouse pointer on the center of droppable area. What should I do to apply hover class at same time when mouse pointer crosses the border. On image 
1. Mouse already on droppable area but hover class is still not applied.
2. Hover class applied but mouse pointer already on the center of droppable area.

```
        `   activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
            hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            accept: '.element',
            greedy: true,
            drop: onLocalDrop`
```

[image]

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code